# В чем ошибка тут ошибка? И что не так с оформлением

Tags: python, случайные-числа, while, print

Почему тут ошибка когда я присвоил переменной x значение либо 1 либо 2, и потом с помощью `print()` захотел вывести, то 1 выводиться, а 2 нет, просто сплошная пустота.

```
print("\t\t\t\t\t\t Привет")
import random  
x = random.randint(1, 2) 
pol = x

x = int(input("Это игра где тебе надо угадать число от 1 до (число постоянно меняется) просто пиши, может повезет. \n"))

print(x)

while x != pol :

if x == 1:
    print()
elif x == 2 :
    print()

else : 
    print("Зачем ты это ввел?")

x = input("Неверно, попробуй ещё\n\n")

print("угадал!")
```

Comment: отформатируйте отступы в вопросе или вы так написали в программе?

Comment: ещё у вас пустые print внутри if

Comment: Ну вы же вызываете print без аргументов, вот он и выводит пустую строку) Если хотите вывести 1, то так и пишите `print(1)`, если значение переменной x, то `print(x)`

Comment: В Python программные блоки основаны ТОЛЬКО(!) на отступах.  всё что внутри цикла нужно табнуть разок(сдвинуть в право)

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь), я тупенький)